# codename one Facebook login not being fired on Android

Tags: android, facebook, codenameone

Looks like recent CN1 updates has broken the Facebook login functionality on android.
This was all working fairly recently but our tester noticed it was broken in the latest build.
The code is based on this sample:
https://www.codenameone.com/facebook-login.html

my code looks like this:

```
        Log.p("about to try and connect to facebook with SDK");
        Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
        fb.setClientId(clientId);
        fb.setRedirectURI(redirectURI + "/");
        fb.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        fb.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void loginSuccessful() {
                Log.p("facebook login complete");
                fbLoginComplete(callback, createNew, fb.getAccessToken().getToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
                Log.p("facebook login error: " + errorMessage);
                callback.failed("There was an error connecting to Facebook");
            }
        });
        if (!fb.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            Log.p("doing login");
            fb.doLogin();
        } else {
            Log.p("already logged in");
            fbLoginComplete(callback, createNew, fb.getAccessToken().getToken());

        }
```

Neither loginSuccessful() nor loginFailed() is being fired on Android. It is working on iOS and in the simulator.

Comment: Did you test against the latest (not 3.5) today? There was an issue with intent handling which should have been fixed.

Comment: Ok tested it again in the latest and it's working now, thanks!